Unable to load class 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.KotlinPluginKt' during Gradle sync in Android Studio
I am getting below issue, even I have added all the dependencies and Koltin Plugin.
Android Gradle Plugin version: 8.1.4
Gradle version: 8.2.2
Kotlin version: 1.9.0
Android Studio version: Giraffe | 2023.3.1
Issue - A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
org/jetbrains/kotlin/gradle/plugin/KotlinPluginKt

Unable to load class 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.KotlinPluginKt'.
This is an unexpected error. Please file a bug containing the idea.log file.


`plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")
    id("kotlin-kapt")
    id("com.google.firebase.crashlytics")
    id("com.squareup.sqldelight")
    id("com.apollographql.apollo3") version "3.8.2"
}

android {
    namespace = "com.example.myapp"
    compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.example.myapp"
        minSdk = 21
        targetSdk = 34
    }

    buildFeatures {
        dataBinding = true
        viewBinding = true
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.7.0")
    implementation("androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4")
    implementation("com.apollographql.apollo3:apollo-runtime:3.8.2")
    implementation("com.squareup.sqldelight:android-driver:2.0.0")
    kapt("com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.52")
}`

`plugins {
    id("com.android.application") version "8.1.4" apply false
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android") version "1.9.0" apply false
    id("app.cash.sqldelight") version "2.0.0" apply false
}

buildscript {
    val gradleVersion by extra("8.1.4")
    val kotlinVersion by extra("1.9.0")

    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:$gradleVersion")
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlinVersion")
        classpath("com.apollographql.apollo:apollo-gradle-plugin:2.5.12")
        classpath("com.android.tools.lint:lint:26.3.2")
        classpath("com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.2")
        classpath("com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.6.1")
        classpath("com.squareup.sqldelight:gradle-plugin:1.5.3")
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}`

